# Foreach(Var item in model) problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

<% foreach (var item in Model) {     %>

```
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditUser", "Profile", new { id = item.UserID },null)%>
        </td>
        <td>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("NewUser", "Create", "Profile", new { id = item.Customer },null)%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: item.UserName %>
        </td>
```

I am getting the NewUser Tab with every Edit Tab n also Username tab..I just need it once newhere in the Page, How Can i do that..n this is been done in a

Comment: Move it out of for each..if you want it once..please post more information and be more descriptive ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking but if you only want **one** edit link for the passed in model then you should use the Model object.

### Update based on new information in question

You need to pull the new user action link **out** of the foreach and instead of using `item` you use `Model` instead. If your Model does not contain a `Customer` object you should modify your ViewModel to include it or pass it in using the `ViewData.Customer = SomeCustomerValue` and then instead of using the model you would use `View.Customer` in your aspx page like so

#### Use this method if you're passing in the Customer via the `ViewData`

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("NewUser", "Create", "Profile", new { id = View.Customer },null)%>
```

(in your controller you would do this)

```
public ActionResult SomeAction() {
    ViewData.Customer = CurrentCustomer;

    return View(ListOfUsers);
}
```

#### Use this method if your Model includes the Customer property

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("NewUser", "Create", "Profile", new { id = Model.Customer },null)%>

<% foreach (var item in Model.Users) {     %>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditUser", "Profile", new { id = item.UserID },null)%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: item.UserName %>
        </td>
    </tr>
<% } %>
```

Comment: I am trying it from the mornin but not getting ne alternative to this problem...please help me with this

Comment: <% foreach (var item in Model) {     %>
        
    
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditUser", "Profile", new { id = item.UserID },null)%>
            </td>
            <td>
            <%: Html.ActionLink("NewUser", "Create", "Profile", new { id = item.Customer },null)%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: item.UserName %>
            </td>

Comment: I need Create to be Occuring only once but its occurin with every Edit and UserNames...this in Partialview..Ne idea How to make it occur only once

Comment: Edit your question above and explain what you're expecting. It's hard to figure out exactly what you're asking. What is your model type, for instance?

Comment: I did Now thts the qns i needed to ask

Comment: THank You it was so helpful...it helped me in completing the tasak.